# Enable individual user account validation in ASP.Net Core 2.0 Web API

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I am creating a Web API in ASP.NET Core and wanted to use individual user account validation. Although this option was not present in .NET Core 1.0, I can now see it his option in .Net Core 2.0.

The problem is when I select this option, it is asking me to provide an Azure account Domain and Application ID which I don't have right now.

I want to know if ASP.NET Core does not have this feature added yet, if it is so how could I validate may APIs using oAuth 2.0 with my users present in the database.

I have to build the APIs in my current project and I am not able to move forward as I am not sure how to validate the .NET Core 2.0 APIs using oAuth 2.0.

Comment: There is some info on this issue provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55544847/asp-net-core-webapi-project-with-in-app-store-individual-user-accounts-visual-st